# My light doesn't light up my scene. I don't see it in viewport

Tags: light, lighting

[image]

I need a little help please. I think I misclicked something, my lights suddenly doesn't work even though I set it to a very high value. How can I put it back?

Comment: Every light doesn't work, please help me. Thank you

Comment: Did you uncheck *3D View > Viewport Shading (dropdown) > Scene Lights?*

Comment: please provide your blend file